# how to retrieve rows based on more than one common identifier in SQL

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I have a user visit log table with cookieID, IP, email and other data details.
a user may have visited from more than one IP, different cookieID, or even leave a different email.
I would like to retrieve all the log events of a specific user, based on any of the common identifiers, e.g:

```
Row   cookieID IP          email
1:    1        10.0.0.12   d@m.com
2:    2        10.0.0.12   h@m.org //match to #1 based on common IP
3:    1        192.168.1.1 null //match to #1 based on common cookieID
4:    3        192.168.2.2 r@y.com //match to #5 based on common cookieID
5:    3        10.11.12.13 h@m.org //match to #2 based on email
```

I need to find a way to retrieve all rows in this case, because at some point they all related either by email or by cookieID, or by IP

Anyone has any idea how to implement that efficiently?

Comment: Can you please add a sample result set?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t1.row, t2.row
from   table t1
inner join table t2
on    t1.cookieId = t2.cookieId
or    t1.email = t2.email
or    t1.ip = t2.ip
where t1.row != t2.row
```

Answer (score 0):

In many databases, if you want to do this efficiently, you want to avoid `or` in the `join` conditions.  It is often more efficient to do separate joins:

```
select t1.row, tc.row as cookie_row, te.row as email_row, ti.row as ip_row
from table t1 left outer join
     table tc
     on t1.cookieId = tc.cookieId left outer join
     table te
     on t1.email = te.email left outer join
     table ti
     on t1.ip = te.ip;
```